# Issue with my simple custom wp plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

i made a very simple wp plugin to do some test.. in fact i wanna grab post permalink and futured image path but every time that any post loads it gives me random results.

For example if my post is `http://www.blahblahsite.com/?p=1234`
my plugin will never return this url... each time it returns random
e.g `http://www.balhblahsite.com/?p=4312 etc..`

I need to attach my code at the footer coz i am loading and some other stuff.

MY plugin's code is:

```
<?php

function myfunction(){
echo get_permalink($post->ID);  
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'myfunction');  

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$post is not in the scope of your function.  Use the_post() to bring it into scope.  Change your code to this:

```
<?php

function myfunction(){
the_post();
echo get_permalink($post->ID);  
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'myfunction');  

?>
```